# SQL inner join returning wrong values after join

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join

I have two tables called `ads` and `videos`. The dimensions like `date,ad_id,ad_name,campaign_name` are common in both tables. however, the ads table has `spend` and `impressions` and the `videos` table has `videoviews`. When I group by each of this table the values for the metrics which I am aggregating seems to be fine. But as soon as I join them the return output is incorrect
For eg, if the total spend for day 1 is `100` for a particular ad_id when I join them I see it as `400`.

```
SELECT
  a.date adsdate,   a.campaign_name campaign_name,
  a.ad_group_name ad_group_name,
  a.ad_name ad_name,
  a.ad_id ad_id,
  SUM(a.cost) fb_cost,
  SUM(a.impressions) fb_impressions,
  SUM(b.action_video_view) fb_videoview
FROM
  fb_ads a  inner join
  `fb_videos b ON
   CONCAT(a.date,'_',a.ad_id)=
   CONCAT(b.date,'_',b.ad_id)
GROUP BY
  adsdate,
  campaign_name,
  ad_group_name,
  ad_name,
  ad_id
  HAVING
  ad_id = ‘1234567’
order by 
adsdate asc
```

Comment: Move the condition `ad_id = '1234567'` from HAVING to WHERE as `WHERE a.ad_id = '1234567'`. And if it has one definite value then I do not see the reason for to select it or to mention it in GROUP BY - use literal value instead. Do not use function in ON clause - use separate columns equiality.

Comment: *But as soon as I join them the return output is incorrect For eg, if the total spend for day 1 is 100 for a particular ad_id when I join them I see it as 400.* Join multiplying. Aggregate in subquery then join.

Comment: I am using HAVING to tally results for one ad. I can ignore that. Could you show an example with this reference on how do I agg in subquery and then joing

Comment: *I am using HAVING to tally results for one ad. I can ignore that.* Do it BEFORE grouping, not after.

Comment: I am planning on removing HAVING once I know the join is returning correct values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:

```sql
SELECT adsdate,
       a.campaign_name,
       a.ad_group_name,
       a.ad_name,
       '1234567' ad_id,
       a.fb_cost,
       a.fb_impressions,
       b.fb_videoview
FROM ( SELECT `date` adsdate,
              campaign_name,
              ad_group_name,
              ad_name,
              SUM(cost) fb_cost,
              SUM(impressions) fb_impressions
       FROM fb_ads
       WHERE ad_id = '1234567'
       GROUP BY 1,2,3,4 ) a
JOIN ( SELECT `date` adsdate,
              SUM(action_video_view) fb_videoview
       FROM fb_videos
       WHERE ad_id = '1234567'
       GROUP BY 1 ) b USING (adsdate)
```

---

> How would I do this with by joining using concat – sten

You use the only `ad_id` value (ad_id = ‘1234567’) - so joining by it makes no sense, joining by `adsdate` is enough.

But if you want to join by 2 columns nevertheless then you do not need in concatenation. Use any of the next joining conditions:

```sql
.. ON t1.ad_id = t2.ad_id AND t1.adsdate = t2.adsdate ..
.. ON (t1.ad_id, t1.adsdate) = (t2.ad_id, t2.adsdate) .. 
.. USING (ad_id, adsdate) ..
```

All these forms are absolute equivalents for your expression with `CONCAT` but are more fast and clear.

Comment: That may give the person an answer, but no context to why, nor anyone else with similar to know why.  I would recommend editing your post and putting a description of WHY you are doing the grouping.  Maybe even add clarification of their 100 vs 400 being the result of a Cartesian product via multiple rows.